# cron not running all cronjobs

Tags: cron

I recently had to recreate our web-server from a backup image, and for some reason, some
of the cronjobs are not working, where they did work before the restore.

The server is running Ubuntu 22.04

The path to the cron-job is /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data

As I said, some of the cron-jobs are running, and others just aren't.

```
## PROJECT 1
30 5 * * * curl 'https://project_1_url/cron/cycle/execute'
01 5 * * * curl 'https://project_1_url/cron/search/rebuild'
*** other crons in this project ***

# PROJECT 2
30 7 * * * php /var/www/project_2/artisan cron_1:notify
0 23 * * * php /var/www/project_3/artisan cron_2:alert
*** other crons in this project***


## PROJECT 3
* * * * * php /var/www/project_3/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So, as far as I can tell, Project 1 and Project 2's cron-jobs are all running just fine.

But it doesn't seem like Project 3's cron-job is running at all.

Now, if I go into project_3 and type 'php artisan schedule:run', I get

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

which makes sense, because while the cron-job is supposed to run every minute, it only actually "triggers" anything at certain times of the day.

When I "cheat in" a way to force it to run what would normally be a certain time of day operation in that same cron-job, I get this.

> Running scheduled command: (touch /var/www/project_3/storage/framework/schedule-6386abb6b38f91c825ff1dfc3599451e; '/usr/bin/php5.6' 'artisan' scheduled_item; rm /var/www/project_3/storage/framework/schedule-6386abb6b38f91c825ff1dfc3599451e) > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &

But if it's failing, it's not logging any errors anywhere that I can find in the project error log, or an internal error logging table for that operation.

I have already done `chown www-data:crontab www-data` on the www-data file in crontabs.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: The cron-job was in fact, working fine. It was environmental settings (namely the S3 credentials) that needed to be updated. It was still failing silently, because in the error-catching PHP code, the assumption was that the S3 part of the process couldn't fail.

Comment: You're aware that appending `>> /dev/null 2>&1` to the last job makes sure that no output nor errors are written. So if it's running, it's completely silent ..

Comment: While the cron in project 3 is supposed to run every minute, the PHP code that is executed has two function calls. One is "If it isn't 5 a.m. America/New_York time, don't do anything" and the second is "if it isn't the end of the month at 6:30 p.m. America/New_York time" don't do anything. And it worked fine for years before this.

So it's really not killing the system.

Comment: What is the last job supposed to do?

Comment: How about adding a test function to the last job, so it's creating an empty file when it runs, no matter what? Then you can isolate the problem to see if it's cron or something else.

Comment: The PHP code is in the Laravel framework, so there's a ->withoutOverlapping() function that prevents it from running if it's already running.

Comment: Okay, this is odd. I used crontab -u www-data to remove the dev/null bit from the one cron-job, did sudo service cron restart, and it's still sending the output to dev/null. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: @P.Gearman are you sure output is still going to /dev/null? Unless you have mail forwarding configured for user `www-data`, cron output will be discarded anyway. Try replacing `/dev/null` by a real file name, like `/tmp/cron.out` instead.

Comment: I'm an idiot.

Once I was able to see the output from the cron job (with a faked in "run now" command), it was because our S3 credentials needed to be updated and hadn't been.

Thanks steeldriver.